# IIS 7.5 http requesting basic authentication but https isn't

Tags: iis-7.5, http-basic-authentication

Server 2008 R2

IIS 7.5

Website Panel

I have a multiple sites running that have a specific folder in each site, say PDFs, some changes have been made, but I don't know what and now if you try to access files in the PDFs folder for any site it will ask for credentials, however if your browse to the site using https, you'll see the PDF file.

NTFS permissions include full rights for the user account the sites run on, mime types are correct for said files, adding a text file to the folder still requests credentials, enable directory browsing still causes a prompt, anonymous authentication is turned on.

Any ideas?